# ASP.NET web.config with extra endpoints generated after Update Service Reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-applications, wcf-binding

I recently tried to Update Service Reference in my .NET Web Application but after that I found that web.config contains extra bindings and endpoints, athough there already existed ones before the update.

It happens sometimes on some of my projects and I didn't find out, why.
Has anyone of you any explanation for that behavior? Thanks.

(I found a bunch of questions regarding NOT generating endpoint rows and other issues, but couldn't find any of this topic..)

Comment: This is an indication you should not be using service references. Try consuming the services directly using ChannelFactory

Comment: I enjoy the benefit, that I can freely use the classes supplied by the service. If I hadn't the service reference added - no classes could be used directly, because visual studio wouldn't give me the classes at design time, am I right?
I mean - the Reference.cs file holds the definitions of types supplied by the service, thus can be used in my code. If I would do the binding programmatically, no types be known at design time. I never used any other approach to connect WCF, nor can imagine that..

Comment: The classes provided by the service references are not the same classes used by the service. They are copies. I mean you should directly reference (either via a project reference in visual studio or a binary reference ideally via NuGet) the assembly which contains the service definition. You can then call the service directly using a WCF channel, referencing the same classes in your code from which the service itself is built. This is much simpler and more direct than using a service reference. You also avoid having problems like the one you are asking about.